# AirPrint in a Sencha Touch/PhoneGap app

Tags: ipad, printing, jqtouch, cordova, sencha-touch

Since the release of AirPrint in iOS 4.2

How can we print from a Sencha or jQTouch app wrapped in a PhoneGap wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

[You can't yet.](https://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/9a40ece6ccec080e?pli=1)

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for Android or Blackberry, but iOS apps can print to two types of printers:

1. AirPrint certified printers
2. Ones certified by Apple as part of their MFi Program (http://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/). These tend to be for specific purposes, such as receipt printers though.

You can print to AirPrint printers from an iOS PhoneGap application using the Phonegap plugin called "PrintPlugin": https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/PrintPlugin